# Reading Win7 current logged username in web application

Tags: c#, windows, iis-7

I had been stuck with the problem and research for it for few days but to no avail.

I'm working on a c# project and my program will automactically read the username from the user's windows whenever the user try to access the web application through the internet.

I tried with the following commands below and it works when I'm debugging the program/ running from localhost in the server. It managed to grab my username from windows and appear on the application.

1. (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name);
2. (System.Environment.UserName);
3. (WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
4. (Page.User.Identity.Name);
5. (System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);

However, they did not work when I publish it and tried to access them from the web.

Instead, it gives me the following ID which I suspect is from the IIS7/ windows server 2008 that I host my site at. Rather than giving me the username from the user's console.

1. -there is no value-
2. -it gives me my server name
3. NTAUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE
4. -there is no value-
5. NTAUTHORITY\NETWORKSERVICE

May I know what went wrong in this case?

Another thing, through my research, I learnt how to get the username/ userdomain through the cmd.exe with commands below.

1. echo %username%
2. set username
3. wmic useraccount where name=%username% get name
4. wmic useraccount where name=%username% get sid
5. whoami
6. whoami/user

May I know if it's possible to apply these commands in windows visual studio for me to read the username from the user'windows when they access my webpage?

So, I hope I can get some advice from the users from this community. Thank you!

Comment: System.Enviroment.UserName is the right thing,  is this running as a service or something?

Comment: oh, a web site, there may not be anyone logged in?

Comment: @KeithNicholas - I guess the real question should be "how to configure impersonation for ASP.Net site", but this would be offtopic as it is way too easy to find an answer with search.

Comment: It's running as a web site. The program would read the username from the user's windows console and save it as a string. From there, I would use the information and check against my database for authentication and redirect the user to respective pages.

Comment: @KeithNicholas sorry, i forgot to tag you in my reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem already.

Problem lies in the IIS. I checked against the authentication method and turned off everything except windows. From there, I checked against the web.config and ensure that the  is turned to "false".

I also used HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name to get the username from the user's console.